# Vector:: begin() vs Array::begin()

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

I got confused with the iterator:

```
vector<int>::iterator first_vector = viktor.begin();

array<int,14> j = {7,3,4};

array<int,14>::iterator first_array= j.begin();

cout<<(first_vector); // Error
cout<<(first_array);  // Output :: 0xeb1ebff940
```

As shown, I am trying to get the address where the iterator is pointing to. With the array it works, but with the vector it doesn't, and I am getting this error:

> error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::vector<int>::iterator')

What am I missing here?

I tried accessing the vector iterator with `&` but as I understand, this will just return the address where the `first` value is saved in memory, and not the address of the iterator itself.

Comment: I'm guessing you're actually looking for `*first_array` and `*first_vector`

Comment: What is `first`?

Comment: Iterators are inspired by pointers, and they are **sometimes** implemented as pointers, but often they are not. If you want the address of the element that an iterator points at, take the address of the element: `&*iter`.

Comment: @273K first_vector or first_array. I meant it in any case.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators are designed to *mimic* pointers, but they *may or may not* actually *be* pointers.

In the case of `std::vector` (and most containers), the `iterator` is usually implemented as a proxy object.  That is why you are getting the error, since there is no `operator<<` defined for that proxy.

In the case of `std::array`, the `iterator` is usually implemented as a raw pointer, and there is a default `operator<<` defined for raw pointers.

> As shown, I am trying to get the address where the iterator is pointing to.

The correct way to do that is to *dereference* the iterator, and then get the address of the referred item, eg:

```
cout << &(*first_vector); // address of value being referred to
cout << &(*first_array); // address of value being referred to
```

> I tried accessing the vector iterator with `&` but as I understand, this will just return the address where the `first` value is saved in memory, and not the address of the iterator itself.

That is incorrect, it is the other way around.  Using `&` on the iterator itself will get the address of the iterator itself, not the address of the item that the iterator refers to.

```
cout << &first_vector; // address of iterator itself
cout << &first_array; // address of iterator itself
```

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was waiting for.Thank you.